# How to output lines 800-900 of a file with a unix command?

Tags: command-line, tail, head

I want to output all lines between a and b in a file.

This works but seems like overkill:

```
head -n 900 file.txt | tail -n 100
```

My lack of unix knowledge seems to be the limit here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
sed -n '800,900p' file.txt
```

This will print (`p`) lines 800 through 900, including both line 800 and 900 (i.e. 101 lines in total). It will not print any other lines (`-n`).

Adjust from 800 to 801 and/or 900 to 899 to make it do exactly what you think "between 800 and 900" should mean in your case.

Comment: perfect! Thanks! I found the exact same tip on a blog post with further examples – see my answer

Answer (score 5):

Found a prettier way: Using sed, to print out only lines between a and b:

```
sed -n -e 800,900p filename.txt
```

From the blog post: [Using sed to extract lines in a text file](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-sed-to-extract-lines-in-text-file.html)

One way I am using it is to find (and diff) similar sections of files:

```
 sed -n -e 705,830p mnetframe.css > tmp1; \
 sed -n -e 830,955p mnetframe.css > tmp2; \
 diff --side-by-side tmp1 tmp2
```

Which will give me a nice side-by-side comparison of similar sections of a file :)